# What is the svn equivalent for "git add -u"?

Tags: git, svn, git-add

Is there an equivalent in svn like `git add -u`? Basically, stage all the tracked files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is **No**, but in several different pieces:

- There is no command in Subversion which will remove all deleted-in-working-copy files. Subversion generally expects you to use its own commands (`svn copy`, `svn move`, `svn delete`) whenever you modify the name/existence of a file; in the case of copies or moves, this is needed to record the file's history, but for deletions it is purely an annoyance.

  When I have the problem of telling Subversion about many deletions, I usually use the following command. However, this command is **unsafe if any pathnames contain spaces**, and will also need to be adjusted if future versions of Subversion add columns to `status` output (this has happened in the past). (The “right” way to do this would be to use `svn status --xml`, but I don't know of a commonly available tool to select data from XML and run commands or produce output suitable for `xargs -0`.)

  ```
  svn status | grep '?' | cut -c 9- | xargs rm
  ```
- Because Subversion does not have staging as Git does, there is no such thing as staging changed files. The only way to have “unstaged” changes is to specify a list of files explicitly excluding those files when you *commit*.
- This is not what you asked for, but it's closely related topic and useful but obscure: If you want to *add* all new files, you can use this command:

  ```
  svn add --force .
  ```

  The `--force` option when given to `svn add` actually means “if a versioned directory is found, recurse into it and add its children rather than skipping it” — it causes `svn add .` to operate the way `git add .` does for untracked files.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent because SVN doesn't have a staging area.  The usual SVN workflow is:

1. Edit your files or add new files
2. Run `svn add <filename>` to tell SVN you'd like to start versioning this file (see note), if any.
3. Run `svn delete <filename>` to delete a file, if any.
4. Run `svn commit` to send all of the changes to the repository on the server.

So changes to files that are already under version control require nothing more than `svn commit` to be sent to the remote repository; no staging is needed (or possible).

Note: Adding a file is *almost* like staging, but it's only for telling the next `svn commit` command to include a file that previously was not a part of the repository.  The same goes for the `delete` command.